# localhost:8088 does not work on hadoop 3

Tags: hadoop

I want to install hadoop 3 on mint but at the end local host::9870 works fine and show nameNode but although in terminal resource manager starts, localhost:8088 does not works!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlHwz.jpg

Comment: where had  you installed  ? in local ?

Comment: usr/local/hadoop

Comment: try to use your ip

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: resourcemanager  areally  start?    its still running?

Answer (score 2):

With Ubuntu 18.04 and Hadoop 3.1.1 I had the same problem.

I workarounded it by using Java 8 instead of Java 11. I.e. I replaced:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

— with:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

in `etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`.

Comment: Never thought that this will work, but it did! Thanks a lot.
BTW, same configuration: Kubuntu 18.04 and Hadoop 3.1.1